# .grep() with jquery array returns just last digit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain this behaviour of jQuery [**.grep()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

I make a jQuery object array out of this elements name:

```
<div class="small1 other">S1</div>
<div class="small2">S2</div>
<div class="small3">S3</div>
<div class="small4 other">S4</div>
<div class="small5">S5</div>
<div class="small6">S6</div>
```

and then run a `each` with a `.grep()` function inside.

**What I wonder is** why console.log() logs `1` / `2` / `3`, etc and not `small1` / `small2` / `small3`, etc...

```
$('div[class^="small"').each(function () {
    var this_class = $(this).prop('class');
    var filter = $.grep(this_class, function (a) {
        return a ^= 'small';
    });
    console.log(filter[0]);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jFFYU/)

Comment: @dystroy, some elements have many classes I'm trying to "get" only the ones starting with "small". Is it wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a ^= 'small';
```

isn't, as you seem to think, an operator telling if `a` starts with `'small'` but

```
a = a ^ 'small'
```

which returns

```
a ^ 'small'
```

which is `0` when `a` can't be converted to a number.

What you do is you filter the array of characters  made from the class as a string and you return the first one that is a number, hence your result.

In your first iteration, your filtering is equivalent to

```
 $.grep(["s", "m", "a", "l", "l", "1"], function(a) { return a ^='somestring' })
```

which returns

```
 ['1']
```

If you want to get all classes starting with 'small', do

```
 $('div[class^="small"').each(function(){
      var filter = $.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(a) {
           return a.indexOf('small')===0;
      });
      console.log(filter);
 });
```

Comment: Interesting, so by doing wrong (since I thought `^=` would give something else), I actually return the first number of a class that has a number.

Comment: And btw, in that case doesn't `indexOf()` need `^=` ? (i see it doesn't by testing your code, but don't understand why).

Comment: `a.indexOf('small')===0` is true when a starts with "small". I could have used `!a.indexOf('small')`